# How to make 'show_option_all', that comes from wp_list_categoreis, to work with get_categories or with get_terms?

Tags: posts, ajax, taxonomy

My problem is that I want to make an ajax category filter, where it shows the categories, but also to have a button "all Posts" so the user can go back to viewing all posts. My current code is using the function get_terms(), but I can't seem to make it add a category button that when clicked on would automatically show all posts.

I want to use the option that is in wp_list_categories() 'show_option_all' => "All Posts". But I can't find how to use that option with get_terms()

The problem is if I replace my get_terms() function with wp_list_categoreis() my code doesn't work.

Some help would be much appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
$tax = 'album_category';
$terms = get_terms( array (
    'taxonomy' => 'album_category',
    'show_option_all' => 'All',
    ) );
$count = count( $terms );
?>
<ul> <?php
if ( $count > 0 ): ?>
    <div class="post-tags">
    <?php
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, $tax );
        echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '" class="tax-filter" title="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a> ';
    } ?>
    </div>
<?php endif;
if ( $query->have_posts() ): ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Could you just prepend the 'All' entry to $terms before you count them?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you explain?